# Auto Sorting with Excel - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This was working for the longest time but I think I might have done something to mess it up. I have checked it and rechecked and it's no longer sorting my data. The code works in other sheets but I can't figure out why it's not working on this current one.

It gives me error '1004':
Sort method of Range class failed

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

'Don't run this code unless a value is last entered in column "H"
  If Not Target.Column = "8" Then Exit Sub

  'Prevents endless loops
    Application.EnableEvents = False



    'Assumptions
    '1.  Data only housed in Columns H
    '2.  The first row contains headings or labels
    '3   Column "H" is used as the sort criteria

      Me.UsedRange.Sort Key1:=Columns("H"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
      Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Save



End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works if I try it. Is all the data in column H valid? No messed up calculations that cannot be sorted or something?

Comment: that's what I'm saying too. I actually have the code in another section and it works fine. the only thing I have in "H" is the techs name like "joe" or "Phil". It just doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Don't run this code unless a value is last entered in column "H"
  If Not Target.Column = 8 Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox " "
  'Prevents endless loops
    Application.EnableEvents = False



    'Assumptions
    '1.  Data only housed in Columns H
    '2.  The first row contains headings or labels
    '3   Column "H" is used as the sort criteria

      ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Sort Key1:=Columns("H"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
      Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Make sure you have "sortable" data in column **H**

Comment: Only thing I have in H is a name. Nothing that can't be sorted.

Comment: It's highlighting this section oft the code too.


    Me.UsedRange.Sort Key1:=Columns("H"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
      Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

Comment: The header should be in **H1**.  You also need some data in the cells **below H1**

Comment: I have all that :( Just not sure why it's erroring out. Here let me put it in my dropbox and share it.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hs357h82d782fq1/Work%20Requests.xlsm

Comment: okay I think I have narrowed it down to the pivot table. If I go back to a standard table it sorts just fine but for some reason if it is a pivot table it causes an error. Basically I need to sort the data after each entry. Is there another way to do it?